# tinymce setcontent loads only on second load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have tinymce which works fine BUT setcontent works only after it has been loaded once(it comes without content) but after you close and reopen it, then it is with content.

JS:

```
  tinymce.remove();
  tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(r.htmleditorcontent);
```

error on first load:

```
TypeError: n.parser is undefined

..."SetContent",t)):("raw"!==t.format&&(e=new s({validate:n.validate},n.schema).ser...
```

error only occurs on first load

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load content into TinyMCE as a page loads you can use the setContent function to do that ... but you need to make sure that TinyMCE is initialized before you try to use `setContent()`.  In your example you call `init` and then immediately call `setContent()` without checking to see if the editor is loaded.

The best way to do what you want is to put the code to load the content into the configuration object for TinyMCE. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
        this.setContent("<p>My new content</p>");
    });
  }
  ... 
});
```

The `init` function won't get called until the editor has finished initializing so you are sure that everything is ready before the `setContent()` code is called.

I would also note that your code uses `tinymce.activeEditor` - which returns the "Currently active editor instance".  You don't have an active editor instance until someone clicks into the editor to use it so its possible that you have no active editor at the time that code runs.  Using the init ensures you can target that specific instance of TinyMCE via `this`.